# Segmentation Fault in pthread_create()

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

this is my code
`

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SLEEP_TIME 10
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *sleeping (int);  /* thread routine */

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i, status;

    /* Argument of thread function is pointer to integer */
    int *arg = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (arg == NULL) {
        perror("Could not allocate memory for arg");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *arg = SLEEP_TIME;

    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];    /* array of thread IDs */

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
        status = pthread_create (&tid[i], NULL, sleeping(i),(void *) arg);
        if (status != 0){
            printf("Error pthread_create(), error code %i\n", status);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* terminates the process with all threads */
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        status = pthread_join (tid[i], NULL);
        if (status != 0){
            printf("Error pthread_join(), error code %i\n", status);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf ("main() reporting that all %d threads have terminated\n", i);
    return 0;
} /* main */

void *sleeping (int i){
    /* pthreadtypes.h : */
    /* typedef unsigned long int pthread_t; */
    printf ("thread %d belongs to process %d \n",
            i, (int) getpid());
    printf ("thread %d sleeping %d seconds ...\n",
            i, i);
    /* Application logic: argument points to integer */
    sleep(i);
    printf ("\nthread %d awakening\n", i);
}
```

I want to create 5 Threads and want them to print their start number from the array and sleep for the seconds of their start number. It works for thread 0 but after that it comes to a SIGSEGV. I don't know what causes the Segmentation Fault. Maybe someone can help me

The output is :

```
thread 0 belongs to process 8435 
thread 0 sleeping 0 seconds ...

thread 0 awakening
thread 1 belongs to process 8435 
thread 1 sleeping 1 seconds ...

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: And this is why you want to always, and I men *always*, use at least `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to be passing `sleeping` to `pthread_create`, but instead you're calling it from the main thread and passing its return value to `pthread_create`. And once you fix this, then you should stop using the same allocation for all of the threads, since that will cause a race condition if you try to put each one's thread number in it. There are a few other minor problems with your code too, but once you fix this one and all of your compiler warnings, it will start to work.